# Using PDO to look up records in one table and append data to another

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 2 tables, each with 3 columns

`Table1` has a columns, `id`, `code` and `name` 
`Table2` has a columns, `id`, `name` and `table1id`

When new records are created in `Table2` the column `table1id` needs to be filled out with the id `Table1` has for that name.

The query must look at the last id created in `Table2` and match the `Table2` name column with the name in `Table1` and then append the id associated with the name to `Table2`.

**How can this be done correctly? The following is the PDO structure I have:**

```
    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `Table2` SET `table1id` = :last_id_0) WHERE `id` = :last_id');
    $stmt->execute([

                  ]);
```

The variable `:table1id` should be based on the last created record in `Table2` but I am unsure with how to continue from here.

**This is a visual representation of the two tables described:**
[image]

UPDATE:

Last inserted id is assigned to the variable $last_id like this:

```
   $stmt = $conn->prepare( ' INSERT INTO `Table2` (`name`)
VALUES (:name  ) ' );
    $stmt->execute([
    'name' => $_POST['name']
                    ])

    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not saying `table2` when you actually mean `table1`? And could you show us the code for the insert from which you get the last insert id?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No Table2 is the one being updated while Table1 stays unchanged

Comment: When new records are created in Table2 the column table1id needs to be filled out with the id Table1 has for that name. this sentence is not clear. I think it should be when new records are created in Table1, then In table2 table1id will be update based on last inserted id of table1.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have updated my post with the last insert id info

Comment: @ShivendraSingh But in my example records are being created in `Table2`,  a new record is created when `name` is inserted into `Table2` the id column in `Table2` is autoincremented so the only field missing is `tableid1`. This is the value I am trying to get from `Table1`. Does that make sense?

Comment: This will assume that the name is unique.  But normally (as mentioned above) you would create the table1 record, fetch the last insert id and the create the table2 record with this filled in.

Comment: So the information in table2 basically duplicates that from table1? What's the point in having a table2 then? It seems you ovethinked your table structure the same way you overthinked your queries. Keep everything as simple as possible and have no hard time writing your queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you want. I assume `table1` has already existed for a long time, and all you do is insert a row into `table2`. You can use an [INSERT INTO SELECT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select) like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `Table2` (`name`, `table1id`)
                        SELECT `name`, `id`
                        FROM `table1`
                        WHERE `table1`.`name` = :name');
$stmt->execute(['name' => $_POST['name']]);
```

This query inserts a new row into `table2` using the selected name and id from `table1`. The selected record in `table1` is the one with the matching name.

Please note that this *will only work* if the names in `table1` are unique.

Comment: What if for example there was a fourth column called "Ready" and the insert query must also Insert the value "Yes" into that column along with `table1id` coming from Table1?

Comment: I'm just wondering how your format will work with hardcoded values

Comment: @PeterDavon  You can do `INSERT INTO Table2 (name, table1id, Ready) SELECT name, id, 'Yes' FROM table1 WHERE table1.name = :name`

Comment: Oh I see so the 'Yes' is understood to be "hard coded" and not something from table1?

Comment: @PeterDavon Yes, that is indeed the case. But better do not use this to put PHP variables in your query. That's frowned upon due to the danger of [SQL-injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Unless it is part of prepared statement

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I completely understand how this can be done now. If possible can you please take a look at this other question I had? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116586/using-the-money-function-in-php-when-creating-json

Answer (score 1):

if you need to change table2.table1id according to table1.name.

```
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();             
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE Table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON Table1.name = Table2.name
SET Table2.table1id = :id
WHERE Table1.name = :name');

$stmt->execute(['id'=>$last_id , 'name' => $_POST['name']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to write a query which is just verbatim your requirement?

> look up records in one table

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id from table1 where name=?');
$stmt->execute([$_POST['name']]);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

> append data to another

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `Table2` (`table1id`) VALUES (:t1id)');
$stmt->execute(['t1id' => $row['id']);
```

Note that it's a very bad idea to duplicate data in the tables, so it's best to keep the name only in table1. You can always have it for table2 using JOIN.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, it is simple, but you would need 2 queries: One to insert a new row into `table2` and another to set the `table1id`. Your answer leaves out the first one. And where is `:last_id` coming from?

Comment: The OP has a hard time constructing basic queries, so indeed simplicity is most important here.

Comment: I agree. But I don't think `$conn->lastInsertId();`, in the first bit of code in the question, will actually return the last row just inserted into `table1`. We assume that, but look at the last bit of code in the question. So where is your `:last_id` coming from?