# Using the money_function() in PHP when creating JSON

Tags: php

The following PHP script looks at data from mySQL table and creates string array in JSON.

The two values presented in the array are `sumTotal` and `numvalue`.

I would like to format both of these values as currency with the proper decimal placement.

I know that the money_format() function can be implemented somehow but I am having trouble understanding how this could be done.

**The following is what I have so far:**

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql =  "SELECT name, SUM(value) as numvalue 
         FROM Table1
            LEFT JOIN Table2 USING(DevName)
         WHERE name <> '' 
         and name is not null
         GROUP BY name";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // you want an array of objects, so create an object to sum the sub totals
    $total = new stdClass;
    $total->sumTotal = 0;

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);

        $total->sumTotal = bcadd($total->sumTotal, $row->numvalue);
    }

    $resultArray[] = $total;
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Best to format things only at the last moment (in the presentation layer) then if you ever need to use this data in an intemediary step it is just numbers and does not have the confusing currency symbols etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly If you don't mind, could you please show me an example of how this could be implemented in my script? I would really appreciate it

Comment: The point @RiggsFolly made was to do this in the presentation layer, which is not part of your current script. That would be the script that consumes the json on the client side and displays it to the end user.

Comment: Oh I see, the reason I was looking for workarounds from using the presentation later is the JSON array makes all of the values into strings. sumValue and sumTotal are both numbers, but I don’t understand how the JSON can show they are numbers instead of strings..basically all of the numbers in the JSON have “” around them.